# Unwanted splitting of file name in Perl. BUG?

Tags: perl, file, file-io, split

I want to know the files within a directory tree. Something like this

```
TOP -> SECOND -> FOLDERS 1-3 -> NAME -> Files
```

I did not generate these files but they are formatted as such

```
1234 ACS. (Description).txt
```

Yes that is white space in there

My issue is when I'm reading .txt files from the "NAME" folder

```
opendir(DIR, $top.$second) or die "CANNOT OPEN SECOND DIRECTORY\n";
@nameFolders = grep { !/^\.|\.\.$/ }  readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

foreach(@nameFolders){
        $folder = $_;
        if($_ =~ /\.txt$/){ next; } #sometimes .txt files are here but I took care of them earlier in the code and that works just fine
        #print $_."\n"; #Output is 100% perfect here
        opendir FIL, $top.$second."/".$folder or die "CANNOT OPEN NAME DIRECTORY\n";
        @files = grep  { /\.txt$/ } readdir(FIL);
        closedir(FIL);

        foreach(@files){
            $fileName = $_;
            print $fileName."\n"; #HERE IS MY PROBLEM OUTPUT IS BELOW
            @fileName = split / /, $fileName;
            $numID = $fileName[0];
            $goodFiles{$fileName}=$numID;
        }

}

OUTPUT: 
     1234 ACS. (STUFF).txt
     ACS.
     1235 ACS. (STUFF).txt
     ACS.
     ...
```

What is going on here? I'm not spiting the file name until after I print, AND it's in the @files array.

I'm at a loss.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  I see no obvious errors that it would point out, but you should always include those pragmas for your own benefit.

Comment: If I do use strict the program crashes on the first line.

Without it it runs fine

Comment: Don't ignore that error under strict and fix it. Use `or die $!` to have more descriptive errors which you did not provide so far.

Comment: Where is the error here? `$masterDirect = "/Users/me/Desktop/cychip/cyto/Oligo/";`

Comment: you forgot to use `my` I guess.

Comment: There is only one `print` in your code. Are you saying that you get `"1234 ACS. (STUFF).txt\nACS.\n"` output by that `print`? That seems very unlikely.

Comment: [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) would be easier, e.g. `my @files = glob ("$top/$second/*/*.txt");`

Comment: I am confident that the code you have shown will not produce that output. Either you haven't shown us the real code, or you are mistaken about which section of your program is responsible.

Comment: Have you tried the File::Find module?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my @directories_to_search = ();
push(@directories_to_search, 'TOP/SECOND/');
find(\&wanted, @directories_to_search);

sub wanted 
{
    my $file = $_;
    if (defined($file) && $file =~ m/.txt$/) 
    {
      print "$file\n";
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1234 ACS. (STUFF).txt
1235 ACS. (STUFF).txt
```